# Pegar nome index json Java Android Studio

Tags: android, json

Como eu posso pegar o nome dos índices de um objeto JSON em Java no Android Studio.

Código:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("nome", "");
            jsonObject.put("sobrenome", "asdasd");
            jsonObject.put("nomeCompleto", "Renato Vieira de Souza");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for(int i=0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++){
            try {
                if(VERIFICAR AQUI SE CADA INDICE DO ARRAY É MENOR QUE 1){
                    Recursos.toastLento(getApplicationContext(), "nome vazio");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

A minha necessidade é detectar qualquer indice que aparece no json e verificar se ele está vazio, com isso eu irei criar um método para validar um json e informar qual json ou quais estão vazios.

Answer (score 1):

Conseguir encontrar a solução, segue:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("nome", "");
            jsonObject.put("sobrenome", "");
            jsonObject.put("nomeCompleto", "Renato Vieira de Souza");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();

        while(keys.hasNext()){
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            try {
                if(jsonObject.getString(key).length() < 1){
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadastroClienteActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Teste");
                    alertDialog.setMessage(key + "Vazia");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "teste", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                    //Recursos.toastLento(getApplicationContext(), key + " Vazia");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```